# Deleting isn't working until a page is refreshed using LocalBase

Tags: reactjs

[image]LocalBase is a workaround for indexedDB, I am able to add and retrieve but I am having hard time creating delete. I know I might be doing something wrong either with wrong state management or thereabout.
Whenever I click on delete, it doesn't have effect unless I refresh the page and if I delete again, the first deleted will be restored. I don't want that to happen, I want to delete without refreshing and if I refresh then everything can be restored.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import notifications from '../mock/notifications.json'
import Localbase from 'localbase'


export default function Notification() {
    const [data, setData] = useState([])

    let db = new Localbase('db');
    db.config.debug = false
    notifications.map((item, index) => {
        return db.collection('notification').add({
             id: item.id, 
             excerpt: item.excerpt,
             content: item.content, 
             date: item.date

    }, `my-key${index}`)
    })
    
   
    useEffect(  () => {
          function getData(){
         db.collection('notification').get().then(response => {
                console.log(response); 
                setData(response)
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error)
            });
     }    
     getData();
    }, [])
    
  
    function onDelete(id){
        db.collection('notification')
          .doc({id:id})
          .delete()
          setData(data.splice(id))
    } 
    return (
        <>
        <ul>
            { data.map((item, index) => 
               (
            <li key={index} >
               <div>
                  <h4>{item.date}</h4>
                  <p>{item.excerpt}</p>
                  <button onClick={()=> 
                        onDelete(id)
                   }
                  >Delete</button>
              </div>
              </li>
            ) )}
        </ul> 
        </>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the dependency i.e. [] to avoid infinite looping in useEffect. In your onDelete function, you have this privilege to the followings but the later is neat and effective.

```
 function onDelete(id){
    let index = data.findIndex(item => item.id === id)
    let newData = [...data] //make a copy of the data i.e. state]
    newData.splice(index, 1)
    setData(newData)
      db.collection('notification')
              .doc({id:id})
              .delete()
    }
```

The later approach

```
function onDelete(id){
    const newData = data.filter((item) => item.id !== id)
    setData(newData)
      db.collection('notification')
              .doc({id:id})
              .delete()
    }
```

Your code is working fine, the .add() will add data content on re-rendering. If you are filling the form or fetching data through API, you will see it work appropriately offline. [my observation]

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import notifications from '../mock/notifications.json'
import Localbase from 'localbase'

export default function Notification() {
    const [data , setData] = useState([])
    let db = new Localbase('db');
    db.config.debug = false
    notifications.map((item, index) => {
        return db.collection('notification').add({
             id: item.id, 
             excerpt: item.excerpt,
             content: item.content, 
             date: item.date
    }, `my-key${index}`)
    })
    useEffect(() => {
         db.collection('notification').get()
           .then(response => {
                setData([...response])
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error)
            });   
    }, [])
    
    function onDelete(id){
        const newData = data.filter((item) => item.id !== id)
        db.collection('notification')
          .doc({id:id})
          .delete()
          setData(newData)
    } 
    return (
        <>
        <ul>
            { data.map((item, index) => 
               (
            <li key={index} >
               <div>
                  <h4>{item.date}</h4>
                  <p>{item.excerpt}</p>
                  <button onClick={()=> onDelete(item.id)}>Delete</button>
              </div>
              </li>
            ) )}
        </ul> 
        </>
    )
}
```